# Docker - Is volume mounted before running CMD

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have docker compose like

```
volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

and dockerfile like

```
WORKDIR /app
CMD [ "npm", "run", "build"]
```

It working but i don't know somecase it don't work?. If volume mounted before CMD run, it will working but i don't know is that true?. I don't want copy file in docker file and if volume mounted before CMD run that sound good.
Anybody know Is volume mounted before running CMD? (more: is that same with command in composer?) any document refer thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, volume is mounted before `CMD` is run.

This is covered in the [OCI runtime spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec/blob/master/config.md#createruntime-hooks) with the "mount operations" before the runtime.

Comment: thankiu, is that same with `command` in compose file